# Integration including the CDF of a standard normal distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution, expected-value, change-of-variable

I am working on a project, where the following integral shows up, and I don't see how to solve this, or to show if it has a closed form solution.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(z)z \text{exp}(-z^2/2)dz$$
It is in the context of probability theory, so an equivalent problem is for $Z$ standard normal distributed with CDF $\Phi$, then to calculate
$$\mathbb{E}_z[\Phi(z)z]$$

I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z\exp(-z^2/2)=-(\exp(-z^2/2))'$, so you can integrate by parts and obtain

$$\begin{align} &\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(z)z\exp(-z^2/2)\,\mathrm dz 
\\[1ex]=~&~{\left[-\Phi(z)\exp(-z^2/2)\right]}_{-\infty}^\infty+\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\exp(-z^2/2))^2\,\mathrm dz 
\\[1ex]=~&~0+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-z^2)\,\mathrm dz
\\[1ex]=~&~\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-y^2/2)\,\mathrm dy
\\[1ex]=~&~\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{align}$$

The rest is trite.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!