# Calculate $\mathbb{E}[Z\Phi(aZ+b)^n]$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, normal-distribution

I am considering the integral $\mathbb{E}[Z\Phi(aZ+b)^n]$, where $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal distribution, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. In the following, I let also $\phi$ denote the pdf of a standard normal distribution.

One approach, with inspiration from [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746947/integration-including-the-cdf-of-a-standard-normal-distribution?noredirect=1#comment10071255_4746947), reduced the integral to
$$ an\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi(az+b)^{n-1}\phi(az+b) \phi(z)dz$$
If $a=1, b=0$, the two density functions could simplify, and after a simple scalation, I would be able to use the result from another of my [recent questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772404/calculate-e-phiaxbn?noredirect=1#comment10140272_4772404).

If $n=1$, the result is on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions#Definite_integrals). However, here it is without proof, and it is also without proof in its reference Owen (1980), so I cannot get inspiration from there.

Another possible method would be to use a similar approach to the one in the [previously mentioned question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772404/calculate-e-phiaxbn?noredirect=1#comment10140272_4772404), but that only changed the $\Phi(aZ+b)^n$ to a multivariate cdf without seemingly helping much.

I hope some of you can help me out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Should follow from steins lemma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show after some algebra that

$$\phi(z)\phi(az+b)=\frac{e^{-b^2/2(a^2+1)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\phi\left(\sqrt{a^2+1}~z+\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)$$

Then after a change of variables the integral reduces to the expression

$$\mathbb{E}(Z\Phi(aZ+b)^n)=n\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\frac{\exp(-b^2/2(a^2+1))}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathbb{E}(\Phi(a'Z+b')^{n-1})$$

where $a':=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}~~,~~b':=\frac{b}{a^2+1}$

and this integral has been calculated in a linked question.

Comment: "You can show after some algebra that ... Then after a change of variables..." This is just Stein's Lemma

Comment: I don't think you can show this using just Stein's lemma. The crucial step is to recombine the product $\phi(z)\phi(az+b)$ into a single exponential, and it is not covered by Stein's lemma, which covers only what is stated in the OP (the integration by parts). If there is an extension of Stein's lemma that I am not aware of, feel free to write an answer about it.

Comment: yes you are right, apologies

Comment: Stein's lemma was an elegant way to reduce the expected value to the highlighted integral in my question. From there, it followed from your calculations @DinosaurEgg

Thank you very much to both of you!